# I am Getting following errors anyone can help me pertains to the React Native Project

Tags: react-native

[image]

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.

> Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.

Answer (score 0):

Try clean gradlew with command:

```
./gradlew clean
```